# How should end-users install dependencies for software

Tags: c++, libraries, dependencies, users

Suppose I have an application written in C++, which uses WxWidgets (or some other library) for gui. When an end-user installs my application, how do I make sure they also install the necessary dependencie(s).

Should I include the source/header files for the library within the download, such that they get compiled with the source files I write, when the user installs? 
Should some external package manager always be used to install dependencies?

When I install a game on windows, I notice it always checks to see if VisualC++11 is installed, how do installers instruct the user computer to install VisualC++?

I can't seem to find any concrete answers to this question (maybe there isn't a concrete answer), so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's your responsibility, not the end-user's. Use an installer program that does that.

Comment: Much of this depends on the platform(s) that you support, what type of users you target and if you distribute binaries or only source code.

Comment: *"When I install a game on windows, I notice it always checks to see if VisualC++11 is installed"* - sounds confused, it seems you are mixing up Visual C++ with the Visual C++ Redistributable Package. If you want to know how to write a program which checks if that package is already installed, search if that question was already asked on Stackoverflow.

Comment: `How do I make sure they also install the necessary dependencies?` -- By including those dependencies in your installer.

Comment: Think of every end user is a potential psychopathic mass murderer who knows where you live (or will find out). Now think what happens when an end user can't install your product. Now think what happens if its the psychopath. Keeping that imagine in your mind, write your installer

Comment: Voting to close as "too broad" -- you could literally [write a book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Definitive-Guide-Windows-Installer/dp/1590592972) on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

End users are not interested in compiling the program. Use an installer app to create a binary package for them. In the app, you can specify the dependencies required by your program.